# Laravel route not defined but route exists and works in tinker

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.6

I'm getting route not defined error :

> Route [my_category.my_item] not defined. (View: /home....blade.php)
>   ...

For following code (c/p from Sentry with a bit of formatting)

```
<?php $__env->startComponent('mail::button', [
  'url' => route('my_category.my_item', [
    'days' => 7,
    'email' => isset($email) ? $email : 'e@example.com',
    'confirm_code' => isset($token) ? $token : 'confirm-code'
  ])
]); ?>
```

This is generated from mail component view. If I SSH to my server, copy the function from above:

```
route('my_category.my_item', [
    'days' => 7,
    'email' => isset($email) ? $email : 'e@example.com',
    'confirm_code' => isset($token) ? $token : 'confirm-code'
  ])
```

and run it in tinker I get my route, no problems. Also if I run `php artisan route:list | grep my_category.my_item` I can see my route there.

Local server: no issues. Staging server: no issues.

Local and Staging servers are using MailHog, and Log, respectively, for mail driver, while production is using MailGun, but I don't see how this could affect anything.

Routes are not cached on any of the servers.

What could I be missing? Thanks!

UPDATE:

Line in `web.php`

```
Route::get('/my-category/my-item/{days}/{email}/{token}', 'MyCategoryController@notifyMe')->name('my_category.my_item');
```

I see now that I have `token` in route instead of `confirm_code`. Let me try to fix that and see what happens. Although it does work on two other servers :/ - Just tried it, still the same behavior.

Comment: Can you show the line where you create this route in your `routes/web.php`?

Comment: change this `'confirm_code' => isset($token) ? $token : 'confirm-code'` to `'token' => isset($token) ? $token : 'confirm-code'`

Comment: Just did it, pushed to servers and still the same.

Comment: just a small query, are you posting exact same code from your route or view file?

Comment: No, but only thing I'm changing is `my-category` and `my-item` in my query it's `something-else` and `another-thing`. Yes and the controller has different name. I think I'm on it, I'm using Localization and just investigating into something. I'll get back and update the question.

Comment: Localization messed it up, see my answer below. What was actually going on is beyond me as I have no clue how it's possible it was working on other servers even while my admin routes were in LL's middleware group. I appreciate your help nevertheless!

Comment: can you show the line for that route from `artisan route:list` that you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I am using [LaravelLocalization](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization) and my admin routes (which are not using this localization - not being translated) were grouped into LL middlware.

Moving my admin routes outside of LL middleware group resolved the issue.

It's still a mystery to me why was this working on my other two servers as the code is the same (double checked it).